# spring измерить время выполнения метода

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Здравствуйте, я хочу измерить с помощью аспекта в Spring время выполнения ВСЕХ методов для этого класса:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ObjectManager {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public Serializable insertObject(Object object) {
        return  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(object);
    }

    public void updateObject(Object object) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(Object object) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(object);
    }
}
```

вот измеряющий класс:

```
@Component
public class Measure {

    private long minTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private long maxTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    public Object measureTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint ) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable throwable) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = end - start;
        if (time > maxTime) maxTime = time;
        if (time < minTime) minTime = time;

      System.out.println(maxTime + " " + minTime);

        return joinPoint;
    }
```

вот XML конфигурация :

```
<aop:config>
        <aop:aspect id="mes" ref="measure">
            <aop:pointcut id="serviceMeasure" expression="execution(* com.components.service.ObjectManager.*(..)  )"/>
            <aop:around method="measureTime"   pointcut-ref="serviceMeasure" />
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
```

У меня возникла проблема на которой я очень сильно застрял, из-за того, что метод insertObject возвращает параметр Serializable.

Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

ошибка была из-за того, что я возвращал в методе measureTime()  , переменную типа ProceedingJoinPoint,  а надо было object.

так правильно:

```
@Component
public class Measure {

    private long minTime = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    private long maxTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    public Object measureTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint ) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Object output = null;
        try {
            output = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throwable.printStackTrace();
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long time = end - start;
        if (time > maxTime) maxTime = time;
        if (time < minTime) minTime = time;

      System.out.println(maxTime + " " + minTime);

         return output;
    }
```